# Responsive layout - how to?

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive

I'm trying to develop an app using Android Studio, but i still haven't figured out how to make this layout responsive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#093A3E"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="One"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3AAFB9"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:text="Two"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#64E9EE"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
                android:paddingTop="40dp"
                android:text="Three"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#97C8EB"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
                android:paddingTop="40dp"
                android:text="Four"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the result I get when running the app on the emulator:

[image]

Basically I want the height of the buttons to be responsive on every android device, so they would stretch all the way to the bottom, but I think I can't just change 'layout_height' of each button.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can weight the heights of the inner LinearLayouts

Comment: Is the scrollView necessary? Also, you can use `ConstraintLayout` instead of making such a deeply nested view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also add `android:layout_weight` to `LinearLayout`
Like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#093A3E"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:text="One"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3AAFB9"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:text="Two"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#64E9EE"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:text="Three"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#97C8EB"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:text="Four"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `ConstraintLayout`, with it, you can easily constrain your `Views` to the parent, set `match_parent` to the `layout_width` or `layout_height` attribute, and you should get your desired result.